# VueJS3: Passing data from route definition

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

Using Vue3. I want to set roles allowed in the route definition, then use that value in `beforeRouteEnter`. Something like:

```js
{
    path: "secure/page",
    name: "SecurePage",
    component: SecurePage,
    params: {role: admin},
}
```

Then

```js
const guard = {
    template: `...`,
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        next(vm => {
            if( 'admin' === vm.$route.params.role) {

            }
        })
    },
}
```

As it doesn't work. Is it possible in any way ?

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access to the router `params` definition from the view as you try. You need something like this:

```
{
    path: "secure/page",
    name: "SecurePage",
    component: SecurePage,
    meta: { role: 'admin' }
}
```

Then in the view instead of `vm.$route.params.role` use `vm.$route.meta.role`:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
        if ('admin' === vm.$route.meta.role) {

        }
    })
}
```

Just so you know, the `beforeRouteEnter` guard does **NOT** have access to this, because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new entering component has not even been created yet.

More about meta fields you can find here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html